# Database access using Windows Login ID

Tags: windows, security, ms-access, winlogon

I need to set up security control on an Access 2010 database (split into App and Data files). I want to control security per 3 levels: db admin, biz admin, biz users. 3 levels of security.

I assign security to users in a table with user's name, user's windows LogIN ID , and security level: 3 fields. Access automatically recognizes the Windows login user using the Access database (via the app only).

How can this be set up ? Any guidance on security control per this setup is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with Access alone (Access can be a "front end"). I believe you need SQL Server. See [Implementing Row- and Cell-Level Security in Classified Databases Using SQL Server 2005](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966395.aspx).